# How to create Emgu Image from System.Drawing.Image?

Tags: image-processing, drawing, jpeg, emgucv

I have a source that gives me a jpeg in memory stream (Bytes).
I can convert it to System.Drawing.Image but I don't know how
to convert it to Emgu Image.

Maybe a direct conversion to Emgu Image is possible ?
I'm working in C# under VS2010.
Thanks.

SW

Answer (score 2):

You can first convert System.Drawing.Image object to a Bitmap and then create an Emgu.CV.Image with that bitmap.
The code is as follows:

```
System.Drawing.Image image;
Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(image);
Emgu.CV.Image = new Emgu.CV.Image<Bgr, Byte>(bmpImage);
```

Better, if you have a memory stream, you can get a bitmap directly from the memory stream

```
MemoryStream ms;
Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(ms);
Emgu.CV.Image = new Emgu.CV.Image<Bgr, Byte>(bmpImage);
```

Comment: Since Emgu version 4.2.0 this won't work anymore. There is an extension method for this now

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your array bytes to Emgu Image<,> with a code like the following...

```
public Image<Bgr, Byte> CreateImageFromBytesArray(byte[] bytes)
{
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
     Bitmap bmpImage = (Bitmap) Image.FromStream(ms);
     return new Image<Bgr, byte>(bmpImage);         
}
```

Comment: You need to cast Image.FromStream to a Bitmap or this won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Using ps2010 solution, I had wrote this to get image from a http:

```
try
{                
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {                    
        data = client.DownloadData("http://LINK TO PICTURE");
    }       
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // error treatment
}

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(Image.FromStream(ms));
Emgu.CV.Image<Bgr, Byte> currentFrame = new Emgu.CV.Image<Bgr, Byte>(bmpImage);
gray = currentFrame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Emgu version 4.2.0 there is no image constructor with bitmap as parameter. There is an extension method for bitmaps now:

```
Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(SomeStream);
var img = bmpImage.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
```

Some details in the history: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Version_History