# C# Timer Pass variables

Tags: c#, image, variables, timer

How can I pass the cor_xy_ficheiro to the timer? It says cor_xy_ficheiro does not exist on contest

https://gyazo.com/4f59951bc65a9b44bb5bd9b36a2b917c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare it outside of the methods, in the global domain. This way it can be accessed by both the `button2_Click` and the `timer_ficheiro_Tick` events

```
Image<Bgr, byte> cor_xy_ficheiro; //declare it outside

private void button2_Click(){ 
    //do something with cor_xy_ficheiro
}

private void timer_ficheiro_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) { //name must match
    //do something with cor_xy_ficheiro
}
```

Also, three important settings for timer: event handler, Interval, and Enabled. Please check if all the three exist:

```
Timer timer_ficheiro = new Timer();    
timer_ficheiro.Tick += timer_ficheiro_Tick; //event handler
timer_ficheiro.Interval = 1000; //interval in ms
timer_ficheiro.Enabled = true; //This you already put
```

Anyway, another note: for the code, you should rather put it in your question as code than put it as image.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476935/how-to-create-emgu-image-from-system-drawing-image) can help you. In short:

```
Emgu.CV.Image cvImg = new Emgu.CV.Image<Bgr, Byte>(cor_xy);
```

Comment: @user5672706: To use `cor_xy_ficheiro` inside `timer_ficheiro_Tick` you should move `cor_xy_ficheiro` out of `button2_Click` scope.