# convert type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'Emgu.CV.IImage'

Tags: c#, winforms, emgucv

I try to convert from bitmap to Image (ImageBox) of EmguCV but it shows me the problem Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'Emgu.CV.IImage' with `this.captureImageBox.Image = val;`
I am using EmguCV V3

```
void SetPic(Bitmap val)
        {
            if (val != null)
            {

                this.captureImageBox.Image = val;
            }
        }
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'Emgu.CV.IImage'

Comment: Try the following answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6470375/6170142

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ctor](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0/document/html/791fbe59-17c0-26e7-efa7-a1d1ad146ac4.htm) takes in a Bitmap.

```
this.captureImageBox.Image = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(val);
```

Comment: beat me by 2 seconds.

Comment: thnx it works, but just a question, I think with V3 new Image<Bgr, Byte> most replaced with Mat??

Comment: @Juste3alfaz not that I'm aware of. Mat and Image are related, but different things. Most things in EmguCV/OpenCV are still done with the `Image<TColor,TDepth>` classes

Comment: requires `using Emgu.CV.Structure;` for Bgr above.

Comment: In version 4 of emgucv this constructor has been removed